# Color of the text in TextView changes color

Tags: android

In android, when I press on a TextView, the text changes color (from white to grey).
Can you please tell me how can I disable that functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TextView gets its styling from whatever styles or themes you have set in your application.  See [android docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for an overview of those.

Part of the default theme is the look and feel of a widget in each of its states.  A selector is used to configure the look and feel in a particular state, for example if it is enabled, or clicked.

To override the behavior you need to create a style (as described in the android doc above) and apply that style to your TextView.